# Add several QGraphicsItem to a QGraphicsScene at once instead (vectorize manner)

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

I have a GUI that creates edges and nodes as to form a network up to several thousand nodes inside a QGraphicsScene. I add every `QGraphicsItem` (`QGraphicsLineItem, QGraphicsRectItem, QGraphicsSimpleTextItem`) in a for loop one at a time, using the QGraphicsScene.addItem() method.

**Issue:**

I have been looking for a method to create, add or edit several items at once in the QGraphicsScene.

An example would be to create and add 100 QGraphicsSimpleTextItem to the QGraphicsScene not on a item by item fashion using a for loop, but using a different method such as  *QGraphicsScene.addSeveralItems([list of QGraphicsSimpleTextItem])*. (fake method)

The same could be said if I wanted to change the text of these already exsiting 100 QGraphicsSimpleTextItem all at once an not on an item by item basis.

So far, I have not been successful in this task as I have not found anything in the QT Documentation.

I have found some topics that could help but is not really a what I want

- qt-thread-updater  https://pypi.org/project/qt-thread-updater/
- QComboBox as the method addItems([item1, item2, item3, … ,item_n])

As an exmaple, when I profile a function that edits an existing QGraphicsSimpleTextItem the more expensive line in terms of time is the QGraphicsSimpleTextItem.setText() (line 1637) that accounts almost for 70% of time for the whole process. This situation is similar when  I create or add the items to the QGraphicsScene by calling the `QGraphicsScene.addItem()` in a foor loop.

The idea would be to call a similar method for example, *QGraphicsScene.addSeveral Items([list of QGraphicsSimpleTextItem)* (fake method) just one time in order to add all my items to the QGraphicsScene.

[image]

**Question:**

Is there a method to add a list `QGraphicsItem` tha could be (`QGraphicsLineItem`, `QGraphicsRectItem`, and `QGraphicsSimpleTextItem`)
at once?, or any other way that could improve performance when adding several items to the scene.

**Expected behavior:**

My goal is to decrease the run time of a function that adds or edits `QGraphicsLineItem`, `QGraphicsRectItem`, and `QGraphicsSimpleTextItem` in to the `QGraphicsScene`.

I use Python 3.8 and PyQt5 version 5.9.2

Comment: Your question is unclear. You are saying that the most expansive function is the `setText()`, so that means that the item already exists. There's no such thing as "vectorialize" adding items (especially because the item types you're listing are not compatible): items must be added singularly through `addItem` (or `scene.addWhatever()`), and those functions are already as fast as they can, since the Qt binding does all optimizations possible on the C++ side. Also, you cannot use threading, as access to UI elements (including those inside a QGraphicsScene) is forbidden from external threads.

Comment: thank you, I will clarify the question.

Comment: Note: you *could* slightly improve performance if those items are only shape based, they are not interactive and you don't care if the graphic elements are all grouped. In that case, instead of using QGraphicsLineItem and QGraphicsRectItem, you can build all elements using a single QPainterPath and then add a QGraphicsPathItem with the full path. Adding rectangles is done with `addRect()`, while for lines you need to use `moveTo()` and `lineTo()` for each line. Obviously, if those lines are interconnected, you don't need to use `moveTo` each time.

Comment: After seeing the update, I still confirm what explained above. There's no optimization available besides what Qt already does, items must be added or edited individually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid a lengthy discussion in the comments, I will answer in a dialog fashion:

**Is there a method to add a list of `QGraphicsItem`s to a `QGraphicsScene`s at once?**

No.

**Can I make one myself?**

Yes, e.g. using [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list). Take a look at [this example](https://drums.scopchanov.de/main.cpp) where I add many items to a `QComboBox` at once:

```
void initComboBox(QComboBox *box, const std::initializer_list<QJsonValue> &args) {
    for (std::initializer_list<QJsonValue>::const_iterator n = args.begin();
         n != args.end(); n++)
        if (n->isObject()) {
            const QJsonObject &json(n->toObject());

            if (json.keys().contains("text") && json.keys().contains("color"))
                box->addItem(json.value("text").toString(), QColor(json.value("color").toString()));
        }
}
```

Hint: Did you notice the loop?

**Would that help me with performance?**

No.

**Why?**

Apart from the code I have shown you above, let's take the `QComboBox::addItems` method, which you have mentioned, as an example. It indeed allows you to specify the whole list of items at once, but look what's going on [behind the scenes](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qcombobox.cpp.html#_ZN9QComboBox11insertItemsEiRK11QStringList):

```
for (int i = 0; i < insertCount; ++i)
    items.append(new QStandardItem(list.at(i)));
```

That's the very loop you want to avoid. No matter how deeply you succeed to hide it, it is there and takes the time, which it needs.

On the other hand, the QGraphicsScene/View framework is designed to operate with a huge amount of items. See [40000 Chips](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-chip-example.html) for example. If you experience performance issues, you might as well have a design problem.